# Regular expression character limit

Tags: regex, limit

I have a regular expression for a 15-character limit:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})$/
```

I would like to remove the character limit. How do I do this?

Comment: Just replace `{1,15}` with `+` to match 1 or more, or with `*` to match 0 or more chars.

Comment: Sorry Jquery verbiage could be wrong but I know what this regex is doing. I just want to know how to remove the character limitation